# Javascript Try Catch for DIV

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to build a catch try to execute some javascript code.  NO JQUERY  I want to identify if a div id ('test') exists and if it doesn't don't execute the code.  How would I do this?  I know the structure of a try catch is

```
try{

}
catch(e){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make things simpler and use `if` instead of `try-catch`. `try-catch` is designed for exceptional situations, when you really don't know what to do throw an error. Throwing an error causes the whole code block to terminate it's execution.

I would do like this:

```
var divId = 'test';

if (document.getElementById(divId)) {
    alert('exists');
} else {
    alert('does not exist');
}
```

There is no need to check `document.getElementById()` result on `null` (in all modern browsers `null` is returned when no element is found). In most JavaScript projects developers skip typing `!== null` since `null` is treated as `false` and DOM object is treated as `true`, so programmers avoid typing obvious things.

Comment: `There is no need to check document.getElementById() result on null`: there is no need, but the code might be more readable (matter of taste IMHO)

Answer (score 4):

use `try-catch` as less as possible: just check whether or not the DOM element exists:

```
if (document.getElementById('test')!=null) {
    // element (div) with id 'test' exists
}
else {
    // it doesn't
}
```