# Having error with simple login form,please resolve my issue and also mention the problem

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an simple login form using javascript,also don't able to find any error,please help me to succesfully implement it.Here is code

```
function validate()
{
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
if (username == "admin" && password == "user")
{
alert("login successfully");
return false;

}
else 
{
alert("login failed");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code should be working fine, unless you've incorrectly trying to access the "username" and "password" elements. In which case, your program will not throw an error. I would suggest handling that error appropriately, which you can see in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20378738/8222441.

If an error does exist with trying to reference your desired elements by its ID, you can console.log something to debug further!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing here seems to be broken. I'm guessing something is wrong with your html, but I can't tell since it's not included.

Here's a way of doing it, this works:

```
<form id="loginForm">
  <input placeholder="username" id="username" />
  <input placeholder="password" id="password" />
  <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
const form = document.getElementById("loginForm")

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(form.elements["username"].value == "admin" && form.elements["password"].value == "user"){
    alert("login successful")
  } else {
    alert("nope")
  }
})
```

Comment: THHTML FILE-   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lan="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Animated Login Form </title>
    
    <script src="login2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form class="box" action="login.html" method="POST">
<h1>
          login
</h1>
<input type="text" name=""placeholder="Enter Username"id="Username">
<input type="password" name=" "placeholder="Enter password"id="password">
<input type="submit" name=" "value="login" onclick="validate()">
      
  
</form>  
    


</body>
</html>

Comment: B/c the type on the last input is set to "submit", it's trying to do the default behavior of the form, which in this case is sending a POST request to login.html. That's why I included e.preventDefault() in my snippet above. 

Assuming this isn't what you want to do, you can change the type to be "button" instead and remove the action and method attributes from the form tag.